# In what version of Python was set initialisation syntax added

Tags: python

I only just noticed this feature today!

```
s={1,2,3} #Set initialisation
t={x for x in s if x!=3} #Set comprehension
t=={1,2}
```

What version is it in? I also noticed that it has set comprehension. Was this added in the same version?

**Resources**

- [Sets in Python 2.4 Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
- [What's new in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sets` module was added in Python 2.3, but the built-in set type was added to the language in 2.4, with essentially the same interface. (As of 2.6, the `sets` module has been deprecated.)

So you can use sets as far back as 2.3, as long as you

```
import sets
```

But you will get a `DeprecationWarning` if you try that import in 2.6

Set comprehensions, and the set literal syntax -- that is, being able to say

```
a = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

are new in Python 3.0. To be very specific, both set literals and set comprehensions were present in Python 3.0a1, the first public release of Python 3.0, from 2007. [Python 3 release notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/NEWS.txt)

The comprehensions and literals were later implemented in 2.7. [3.x Python features incorporated into 2.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer the question, but it is my fault for being unclear

Comment: The special set comprehension syntax with brackets is new to Python 3.0, but you can perform set comprehensions in 2.5 and older with the more verbose (and uglier) `set([i for i in s])`

Comment: It is listed as a new feature in Python 3.0. http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html. It can't be done in Python 2.6

Comment: @Chris: Use a generator expression, it allows to drop the brackets if alone, `set(i for i in s)`. Not ugly IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Well, testing it:

```
>>> s = {1, 2, 3}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s = {1, 2, 3}
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm running 2.5, so I would assume that this syntax was added sometime in 2.6 (Update: actually added in 3.0, but Ian beat me). I should probably be upgrading sometime soon. I'm glad they added a syntax for it - I'm rather tired of `set([1, 2, 3])`.

Set comprehensions have probably been around since sets were first created. The Python documentation site isn't very clear, but I wouldn't imagine sets would be too useful without iterators.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in the question. This is when sets were added and set operators. Don't downvote this answer

Answer (score 0):

The set literal and set and dict comprehension syntaxes were backported to 2.x trunk, about 2-3 days ago. So I guess this feature should be available from python 2.7.